# Syntax Error: unexpected token 'else' while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, compiler-errors

Receiving below error while trying to add dropdown logic to the navbar. Error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/myfile/app/views/layouts/boilerplate.ejs:22
    20| 
    21|   <body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
 >> 22|     <%- include('../partials/navbar') %> 
    23| 
    24|     <main class="container mt-5">
    25|         <%- include('../partials/flash') %> 

    Unexpected token 'else' in /Users/myfile/app/views/partials/navbar.ejs while compiling ejs

    If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
    https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
    Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
```

Here's my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #00305a;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
          aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link active" href="/events">Events</a>
            <a class="nav-link active" href="/artists">Artists</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <% if(currentUser) {%> 
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/artists/<%=artist.id%>/edit">Edit profile</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
              <% } %> 
            </li>  
          <a class="nav-link active" href="/logout">Logout</a>
            <% } else { %> 
              <a class="nav-link active" href="/login">Login</a>
              <a class="nav-link active" href="/artists/new">Sign Up</a>
            <% } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the part of my boilerplate layout that includes the Navbar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Boilerplate!!</title>

</head>

       <body class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
         <%- include('../partials/navbar') %> 
     <main class="container mt-5">
         <%- include('../partials/flash') %> 
         <%- body %>
     </main> 

     <%- include('../partials/footer') %> 


 </body>

 </html>
```

I *think* it's because I have to define a global variable on my app.js but not sure if that's the case exactly. Including my app.use variables for context:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.session);
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
})
```

How do I get my dropdown in my navbar to let a user "edit" their profile?

Comment: You have `if () { }} else`   remove `<% } %>` or move the else up

Comment: When I do I get error 'artist is not defined' from row <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/artists/<%=artist.id%>/edit">Edit profile</a></li>. This is why I was thinking I have to define it globally?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `<% } %>` in the navbar html page. Just remove this tag after `</ul>`

Comment: Thanks @ashan Jamal you're right I do need to remove that bracket but when I do I get error 'artist is not defined' from row  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/artists/<%=artist.id%>/edit">Edit profile</a></li>. This is why I was thinking I have to define it globally?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out-- I had to change the name of the ejs variable because I had already defined currentUser:

From: href="/artists/<%=artist.id%>/edit">Edit profile

To: href="/artists/<%=currentUser.id%>/edit">Edit profile

The artist's id had already been passed into currentUser so I was able to pull it out of there.